# Paperclip crashing Ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Ruby interpreter frequently crashes when viewing images called with the @user.photo.url method from paperclip. Requires me to restart the server.
Sometimes the view shows up fine, I hit F5 without making any changes to any code and it crashes.

Upload is working fine.

Using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: What platform? I don't see how; isn't it just serving physical images at that point?

Comment: I know it's strange, but that view is only loading pictures through paperclip, there's no other code except for the header, but the header is present on every page, and no other causes this crash.

Comment: Configuring ruby+rails on windows was painful for me. Do you have access to a linux box to try the same code?

Comment: Not atm no. The server and everything else has been running without problems.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 plus Windows 7 equals pain - I am in the same boat and having similar issues. From what I can tell it has nothing to do with paperclip. The Ruby 1.9 interpreter will crash frequently if there is a missing resource on your page (image, stylesheet, js file, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade ruby to Ruby 1.9.3-p125. This helped me.